# How to find parent table for the row

Tags: jquery

I have a complex html file. I want to select a input[type=text] previous to the table when table row is clicked.

A html snippet goes here

```
<input type=text/>
<table>
  <tr>
  ...
  </tr>
</table>

$('tr').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('table').prev(input[type=text]).val();
});
```

This throws

```
`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableRowElement> has no method`closest
```

How to write jQuery selector to select the input when table row is clicked?

Comment: Ideally you'd want this: `$( this ).closest( '.common' ).find( '.field' );`.

Comment: I tried with parent(), this throws Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableRowElement> has no method 'parent'

Comment: are you sure you typed function correctly, and quoted the input. This is really all about typos, as the selector works -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/S5myX/) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).parent('table').prev('input[type="text"]').val()
```

OR

```
$(table).on('click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).[prev/siblings/closest]('input[type="text"]').val();
});
```

Comment: Hard-coding the table-to-input relationship like that is hardly a good approach. Imagine putting that field in a `<label>` after some time, and wondering why the JS stopped working.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Agreed, but that's what the OP asked for. Do suggest alternatives please.

Comment: I've posted it in a comment above.

Comment: Keeping in mind what @ŠimeVidas said, you can also use `.siblings('input...')` if there is only one textbox adjacent to each table.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).parents('table')[0].prev(input[type=text]).val();` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try parent()

```
 $(this).parent('table').prev(input[type=text]).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a living demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/ceETY/2/

You can use this:

```
$(this).parent('table').prev('input:text').val();
```